# Debugging Errors That I Cannot Fix

Tags: php, sql

I've been working on a php script to utilize several different submit buttons to update, edit, and delete table information in an SQL database.  Lately I have been getting this error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 30720 bytes) in
>   /home/peroral/public_html/InsertProducts.php on line 46

I have tried using `ini_set("memory_limit","128M");` in my php file in an attempt to get it work, but it does not matter how much more memory I allocate (I've gone up to 512) i still get the error.  Does anyone have any advice on getting my script to work?

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lange="en">

<!--orders.php-->

<html>
<head>
<title> InsertProducts.html form </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
    require 'InsertProducts.php';
    $db = DB::connect('mysql://peroal:*******@localhost/peroral');

    if (DB::isError($db))
        {die("Cannot Connect " . $db->getMessage());}

    extract($_POST);    


        if(isset($create))
            {

            $q = $db->query("Create Table Products
            id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id), Product_Name VARCHAR (255), Product_Type VARCHAR (50), Product_Price DECIMAL (4,2), LOR INT");
            VALUES ('$Name', '$Type', $Price, $LOR);
        if (!$q)
                die("Unable to Create Table." . $q->getMessage());
        else
                print("Table Was Created.<br />");
            }

        else if(isset ($delete))
            { $q = $db ->query("DROP TABLE Products");

            if($q)
                print("Table Products Was Deleted.<br />");
            else
                print ("Unable to Delete Products Table.<br />");
            }

        else if (isset ($add))
            {   $q = $db ->query("INSERT INTO Products (Product_Name, Product_Type, Product_Price, LOR);
                VALUES ('$name, $type, $price, $lor)");

            if(!$q)
                print ("Query Failed.<br />");
            else
                print ("Query Successful.<br />");
            }
        else if (isset ($update))
            {   $q = $db ->query ("UPDATE Product_Name, Product_Type, Product_Price, LOR");
            if(!q)
                print ("Query Failed.<br />");
            else
                print ("Query Successful.<br />");
            }   
        else if (isset ($display))
            {  $sql = "SELECT Product_Name, Product_Type, Product_Price, LOR FROM products WHERE price >= $min_price
                AND price <= $max_price AND Product_Name LIKE '$name'";
            if($LOR == 'Liquor')
                $sql.='AND LOR=1';
            else
                $sql.='AND LOR=0';
            }   
        print '<table>';
        print '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Price</th><th>LOR</th>';
        while ($row =$q->fetchRow())
            {
                $numberOfRows++;
                if($row[3] ==1)
                {
                 $LOR="Liquor";
                 }
                else
                {
                 $LOR="Beer";
                }
            print"<tr>";
            print"<td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$LOR</td>";
            print "</tr>";  
            }
        print'</table>';    

        if($numberOfRows == 0)
            print"No Match Found";
        ?>

</body>
</html>     



    ?>
```

Comment: Have you even googled a solution?  This has been asked sooooo many times. http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/how-to-solve-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-8388608-bytes-exhausted/

Comment: That's how I got the ini_set("memory_limit","128M"); code.

Comment: Do not use `extract($_POST)`. This is really dangerous. A hacker could directly overwrite variables in your code

Comment: @user2322110 Well, change this in your php.ini to allow more memory, a usual cause for this is that your script might be looping without exit. Can you make line 46 more visible..?

Comment: I need to use the extract($_post) because the information is being extracted from an html form.  Here are lines 45 & 46.

Comment: { $q = $db ->query("INSERT INTO Products (Product_Name, Product_Type, Product_Price, LOR);
VALUES ('$name, $type, $price, $lor)");

Comment: No, you do NOT need to use extract($_POST).

Comment: Loop through $_POST instead of extracting it.  This way you know what to expect.

Comment: The error you're receiving is in `InsertProducts.php`, but you're not showing us that code - you're showing the page that includes it. Can you show the code for `InsertProducts.php` and we should, hopefully, be able to help resolve this with you =]

Comment: the whole thing was the InsertProducts.php file.  I just realized I misnamed it.  But, even after updating all of the information and if I remove the require 'InsertProducts.php'; it gives me this error instead

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in /home/peroral/public_html/InsertProducts.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

Your ini_set may or may not be a viable option depending on how your server/host is configured.

If you have access to the php.ini file, change the memory limit there instead, and it should work fine.

Comment: I don't have access to it, because I don't have access to anything in the server.